# How to make an object bounce of edge

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm making a simple game in JavaScript and using the Phaser library. I'm new to this, so hopefully this is not a silly question.

I have made it all work perfectly but I would love to know how to get the rocks to bounce of the walls, rather than go through them and appear on the other side.

It has something to do with this function:

I was told by someone to

> "If it hits Width: 940 then x = 940 and you start going back 939, `i--`, etc. Height will continue as normal. Rather than resetting i.e `shot.reset(x, y);`.
>
> If you hit the bottom or top then do the same to height, keeping width the same."

However, I am not sure how to implement this into the code. I have tried but failed :) Its very frustrating, so any help on this matter would be amazing.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure to get the point, but you can try something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Qg4cV/8/ (I just added `collideWorldBounds` and `bounce` to the body of the rocks in the creation)

Comment: Ah that also works :0 thanks is well xx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, I create a velocity vector, wich represents the "speed" of my objects. 
On each frame, I add that velocity vector to the position vector. When I want my object to move to the opposite direction, I multiply my vector by -1.

Create a vector like that, and when your object collid an edge, multiply it by -1.

You can make a lot of things with this type of vector, such as smooth speed decrease, inspace-like movements etc...

e.g:

```
//on init
var velocity = {x: 10; y: 10};
var pos = {x: 10; y:10};

//on frame update
pos.x += velocity.x;
pos.y += velocity.y

//on edge collision
velocity.x = velocity.x * -1;
velocity.y = velocity.y * -1;
```

Comment: hmm i am not exactly sure what u mean sorry , very new to this, would it be possbile to show me ?